# android custom list item xml root layout padding

Tags: android, xml, list, layout

I have a custom list view item layout. Root item of this layout has 10dp padding but when I load the list on the device there are no space between the items. In my case it means padding doesn't work for root item. Do you know why this happen?`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.hipo.volt.ui.custom.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.hipo.volt.ui.custom.VoltTextView
        style="@style/textview_dark_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: post your xml please :), that would be nice

Comment: if you want to give space between items then you have to use listDivider in your ListView xml file

Comment: you are right @RohitGoswami it could work for the space between items but i want to learn the reason why padding doesn't work. I posted my xml :)